# How can I get sublime to stop outlining my comments?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, text-editor

I have been trying to get sublime to stop outlining my comments with python but am having a hard time. I am not sure if it is one of the packages I downloaded, or the language I am using. It makes it difficult to read whats in the comments sometimes. I am new to programming and this text editor and would appreciate any help, thanks! Here's what it looks like

[image]

The packages I installed are `anaconda`, `Djaneiro`, `Emmet`, `PyV8`, `requirementstxt`, `sidebarenhancements`, `sublimeLinter`, and `sublimeREPL`.

Comment: Can you give us a list of the packages you've installed? You can find this in Preferences -> Package Control -> List Packages.

Comment: The linting looks like PEP violations

Comment: As @s3cur3 has already said, we'd need to see the packages installed. It *looks* like an issue I had previously. You may have an Annoconda package installed, and need to add `"anaconda_linting": false` to your annoconda settings.

Comment: yes the packages are anaconda, Djaneiro, Emmet, PyV8, requirementstxt, sidebarenhancements, sublimeLinter, and sublimeREPL. Also I remember doing something that has to do with PEP, it was on a youtube video, how to I take care of that?

Comment: Thanks alot! setting '"anaconda_linting":false'  seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed the `anaconda` package you need to add the following package setting:

```
"anaconda_linting":false
```

See the [*Anaconda Python IDE* docs](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#disabling-the-linter)

> There is people that doesn’t care about linting or they just use another plugin to do it, they can completely deactivate this feature setting the `anaconda_linting` as `false` in the anaconda or project configuration.
>   
>   ***note***: imports validation depends of anaconda linting handler so it will not work if anaconda linting is disabled